# Calculate the percentage of area where the number rises between two raster files in Python?

Tags: python, gdal

I have two raster files with the same coordinator. I want to first calculate the difference between the two raster files. Then, I want to calculate the percentage of area where the number increases by 10 or more (the number decreases by 10 or more). I am wondering what is the fastest way to do so. Do I need to polygonize the raster to calculate the percentage or I can do it faster as raster format?

Comment: Stick with raster calculations if possible for the sake of efficiency. Sounds like you could use some simple band math in a raster calculator. For example `Raster1 - Raster2 = Difference Raster`. Then classify the difference raster so that value >10 or <10 are assigned a value such as 1 and everything else a value of 0. More details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110177/8104

Answer (score 1):

Here is a programmatic solution using gdal and pandas.

First using rasterio, numpy, and geocube we can create some sample data :

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import numpy
import rasterio as rio
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

# this is an existing vector consisting of a single polygon geometry
poly_file = ogr.Open('PDC.shp')

# output filename for new raster
output_file = "out_raster.tif"

# make geocube from polygon
out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data='PDC.shp',
    measurements=["id"],
    resolution=(-25, 25),
    fill=-9999,
)
# write original
out_grid['id'].rio.to_raster('in_raster.tif')

# load in original raster with gdal
raster_original = gdal.Open('in_raster.tif')

# create new raster
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
raster_out = driver.Create(output_file,
                           len(out_grid.x),
                           len(out_grid.y),
                           1,
                           gdal.GDT_Int16)

# create data for new raster and write to output
raster_values = numpy.random.choice(
    [-10, 1, 11], size=(len(out_grid.y), len(out_grid.x)), p=[0.33, 0.34, 0.33])
raster_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster_values)

# georeference new raster to match original
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()
raster_out.SetProjection(dest_wkt)
raster_out.SetGeoTransform(raster_original.GetGeoTransform())

# clear variables to close files
raster_original = None
raster_out = None
```

Now compute the differences like @Aaron recommended in the comment, categorize them based on the values, then calculate the proportions:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd

#read in rasters
r1 = gdal.Open('in_raster.tif')
r2 = gdal.Open('out_raster.tif')

#convert to arrays
arr1 = r1.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
arr2 = r2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

#compute differences 
out_arr = arr2 - arr1

#convert to categorical and rename categories 
buckets = pd.Categorical(pd.cut(out_arr.flatten(
), [-12, -1, 1, 12])).rename_categories(['fell', 'remained', 'rose'])

#calculate proportions
proportions = buckets.value_counts() / len(buckets)

#print out result
print(proportions)
```

Output:

[image]