# Setting up Raster Calculater for QGIS Python Console: ImportError?

Tags: qgis, python, raster-calculator

I'm trying to follow the instructions here [How to evaluate raster calculator expressions from the console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console) to set up the python console to to use the raster calculator.

I tried:

```
from qgis.analysis import  QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
```

But that gave

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QgsRasterCalculator
```

The following seems to work fine, but doesn't get me the raster calculator commands.

```
from qgis.analysis import *
```

What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

QgsRasterCalculator requires QGIS 2.0 or higher.  It will not import for QGIS 1.8.