# QGIS from console: raster algebra

Tags: pyqgis, map-algebra

I'm newbie to programming in pyqgis.

I need to perform a simple "GeoTiff * A" type of calculation(where A is a constant), but I am struggling to do so.

I tried processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator') but failed 'coz my constant is NOT a raster.

I suppose I should be using 'qgismodelertools:calculator' or possibly something like to what they use here http://geoexamples.blogspot.it/2012/12/raster-calculations-with-gdal-and-numpy.html

Any clues?

---

[Gene's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141727/115) iss succinct and logical but rasterio does not come out of the QGIS 2.8 box, which I'm using from OSGEO4W.

In the meantime, I used [EikeMike's useful code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141668/115) by turning it into a working, callable function:

```
def raster_calc(RGBI_DS,outFile,constant):

  import processing, os, time, subprocess, array
  from osgeo import gdal  
  from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *  
  from osgeo.gdalconst import *

  # Read Raster dataset
  GDALRgbiDS = gdal.Open(RGBI_DS, GA_ReadOnly )
  band1rot = GDALRgbiDS.GetRasterBand(1)  

  # Convert band to Array
  Rdata = BandReadAsArray(band1rot) * 1.0

  # calculate raster * constant
  dataOut = (Rdata * constant)

  # Export result as Geotiff
  driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")  
  dsOut = driver.Create(outFile, GDALRgbiDS.RasterXSize, GDALRgbiDS.RasterYSize, 1, 
   gdal.GDT_Float32)  
  CopyDatasetInfo(GDALRgbiDS,dsOut)  
  bandOut=dsOut.GetRasterBand(1)  
  BandWriteArray(bandOut, dataOut)

  #Deletion of variables, this actually triggers the writing of the output file
  dsOut =None
  bandOut = None
  driver =None
```

---

Later, I found myself a much easier and shorter solution.

Here it is:

Stick to 'saga:rastercalculator' (or similar algorithm). Simply build the mathematical formula therein as a new variable where your constant is itself a variable. In other words:

```
 import processing

 formula = ('a * %s' % (str(constant))) # where 'a' is going to point to yourraster   and 'constant' is the numeral you want to multiply your raster by
 processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator',yourraster,None,formula,outFile)
```

Comment: The solution lobelius used throws a data source is invalid error. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the question is about PyQGIS and not [GDAL (osgeo)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.11.2) (use [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio), easier, see below in 3) and there are many examples in GIS Stack Exchange as [How to evaluate raster calculator expressions from the console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console)

`processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator')` is the Saga raster Calculator
`processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator')` is the  GRASS GIS raster calculator

To use the QGIS raster calculator in the console,  I detail here the process using the example of [Cómo usar el Raster Calculator desde la Python Console](https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/como-usar-el-raster-calculator-desde-la-python-console/) de José Guerrero (in Spanish)

1) The raster calculator dialog

[image]

2) The script in the console

Characteristics of the raster layer

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
# compare with the values in the dialog
print layer.extent().xMinimum(), layer.extent().xMaximum()
202086.577 205625.414407
print layer.extent().yMinimum(), layer.extent().yMaximum()
88411.048 90534.3504441
print layer.width(), layer.height()
100 60
name = layer.name()
print name
test
bands = layer.bandCount()
print bands
1
```

To use the raster calculator with the only band, the expression is therefore test@1 as in the dialog

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
resultinglayer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
resultinglayer.ref = name + "@1"
resultinglayer.raster = layer
resultinglayer.bandNumber = 1
entries = [resultinglayer]
# perform a simple "GeoTiff * A" type of calculation(where A is a constant)
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('(test@1)*3', 
                          '/Users/Shared/resulting.tif', 
                          'GTiff', 
                          layer.extent(), 
                          layer.width(), 
                          layer.height(), 
                          entries )
calc.processCalculation()
# load the resulting raster layer.
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer('/Users/Shared/resulting.tif', 'resulting')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

3) EikeMike gives you a solution with GDAL, compare with a [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) solution

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('/Users/Shared/test.tif') as original:
    layer = original.read() # or read_band(1), but deprecated
    resultinglayer = layer*3
    kwargs = original.meta
    with rasterio.open("/Users/Shared/resulting.tif", 'w', **kwargs) as output:
         output.write(resultinglayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You find an excerpt of a script of mine. I am using GDAL there and the calculation is done with arrays. Important lines for you are the RGBI_DS - here you put your path and filename. and the line dataout - here you can replace the 2.0 by your constant. I hope this gets you started.

```
import processing, os, time, subprocess, array
from osgeo import gdal  
from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *  
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

# Raster Dataset
RGBI_DS = "D:/Rohdaten/RGBI_DS.img" 

# Read Raster dataset
GDALRgbiDS = gdal.Open(RGBI_DS, GA_ReadOnly )
band1rot = GDALRgbiDS.GetRasterBand(1)  

# Convert band to Array
Rdata = BandReadAsArray(band1rot) * 1.0

# calculate raster * constant
dataOut = (Rdata * 2.0)

# Output
outFile = "D:/NDVI.tif"

# Export result as Geotiff
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")  
dsOut = driver.Create(outFile, GDALRgbiDS.RasterXSize, GDALRgbiDS.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)  
CopyDatasetInfo(GDALRgbiDS,dsOut)  
bandOut=dsOut.GetRasterBand(1)  
BandWriteArray(bandOut, dataOut)

#Deletion of variables, this actually triggers the writing of the output file
dsOut =None
bandOut = None
driver =None
```