# QGIS python script loop for raster calculator

Tags: qgis, python, raster, qgis-processing

How can I write a QGIS script for making a loop of raster calculator through a set of rasters? I know I can read multiple raster by applying:

```
lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for lyr in lddLrs:
```

And I want to apply an easy operation such as “Raster/Raster*Raster” and repeat it through multiple rasters and get the result with the same name of the input raster with a suffix.

Any Idea?

For using the script to make a new tool within the "processing Toolbox - Scripts - Create New Script" I made the following script but it doesn't work. Any idea to fix it?

```
##NoDATA Background=name  
##lyr=multiple raster
##OUT=output raster

import qgis
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculatorEntry, QgsRasterCalculator

# Get layer object
layer = processing.getObject(lyr)
lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for lyr in lddLrs:
    entries = []    
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = 'lyr@1'
    ras.raster = lyr
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras )    
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( '("lyr@1" / "lyr@1") * "lyr@1"', +lyr.name() + "_suffix.tif", 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()
```

[image: resulting tool]

Comment: Are you wanting to select individual rasters from the loaded rasters and run the script on those selected? Or do you want the script to apply to all loaded rasters?

Comment: Indeed, the usefulness of making a script by using the Processing Toolbox  is the possibility of selecting some or all loaded raster through the tool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
import processing

lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
path = "path/to/results//"
for lyr in lddLrs:
    processing.runalg("saga:rastercalculator", lyr, None, "(a/a)*a", True, 7, path + lyr.name() + "_suffix.tif")
```

---

**EDIT** :

If you want to use the [QgsRasterCalculator](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterCalculator.html), you could try using the following (based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console)):

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculatorEntry, QgsRasterCalculator

lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
path = "path/to/results"
for lyr in lddLrs:
    entries = []
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = 'ras@1'
    ras.raster = lyr
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras )
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( '(ras@1 / ras@1) * ras@1', path + lyr.name() + "_suffix.tif", 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()
```

---

**UPDATE**:

You can use the following code in a script which allows you to select individual rasters and run the calculator on them. I've changed the output to a **folder** so that multiple (or single) rasters can be output to the same directory but you can change this:

```
##NoDATA Background=name
##Raster=multiple raster
##OUT=folder

import glob, qgis
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculatorEntry, QgsRasterCalculator
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsRasterLayer

# Split rasters
layers = Raster.split(';')
output_path = OUT + "/"
suffix = "_suffix.tif"

for ras in layers:
    # Get layer object
    lyr = processing.getObjectFromUri(ras)
    entries = []    
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = 'lyr@1'
    ras.raster = lyr
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras )    
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( '(lyr@1 / lyr@1) * lyr@1', output_path + lyr.name() + suffix, 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()

for results in glob.glob(output_path + "*" + suffix): 
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(results)
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Actually I need it to get image background as NoDATA instead of Zero

Comment: Is there a way to make it without using SAGA, but with the QGIS Raster Calculator?

Comment: I mean the QgsRasterCalculator function

Comment: @Nico_77 - Updated my post =)

Comment: I tried the script but it seems like something needs to be fixed. I tried to use "ras@1" instead of ras@1, but even so it doesn't work to me. Maybe does it need to make a DEF function before the "for lyr in lddLrs:"?

Comment: Forget my last comment, the script works!! Either with or without quotation marks.

Comment: @Nico_77 - Nice, good to know! Glad you got it working ;)

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @Nico_77 - As did I ;)

Comment: Joseph - If I use the script as you made within the python console it works good, but I am not able to adapt it for making a new tool through the "processing Toolbox - Scripts - Create New Script". Any idea about fix it?

Comment: I tried, as you can see, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nico_77 - Did you test the updated code I posted? It works as a script for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39892/discussion-between-nico-77-and-joseph).

Comment: The UPDATE works perfectly. Results are saved and loaded into the workspace.

Comment: @Nico_77 - Awesome, glad it works =)

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Joseph needs some adjustments to work in QGIS 3

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculatorEntry, QgsRasterCalculator
from qgis.core import QgsProject

lddLrs = [tree_layer.layer() for tree_layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()]
path = "path/to/output"
for lyr in lddLrs:
    entries = []
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = 'ras@1'
    ras.raster = lyr
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras )
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( '(ras@1 / ras@1) * ras@1', path + lyr.name() + "_suffix.tif", 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()
```