# How to use the Raster Calculator in PyQGIS (Console) in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, raster-calculator, pyqgis-3

I want to use a script to do some raster calculations. I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193455/qgis-python-script-loop-for-raster-calculator) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console) posts which seem to answer this question, however, it seems that they work for QGIS 2 and not for QGIS 3. I think the issues in QGIS 3 arise from using this line

```
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
```

which to my understanding gets each one of the layers in the project (each layer is defined as `lyr` in the loop [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193455/qgis-python-script-loop-for-raster-calculator)). In the second [reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console) the layer is defined as `bohLayer` and i assume it was obtained in a similar way.

I tried using the path to a layer but obtained the following error

```
TypeError: str cannot be converted to qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer in this context
```

So my specific question is how can i call a layer in QGIS 3 to include it in a raster calculation (i.e. how to define `lyr` [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193455/qgis-python-script-loop-for-raster-calculator) or `bohLayer` [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console))?

Alternatively, a more general question is how to use the raster calculator from the console in **QGIS 3**?