# "TypeError: index 0 has type 'QgsRasterLayer' but 'QgsRasterCalculatorEntry' is expected." error when calculating NDVI Landsat 5 with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, raster-calculator, geoprocessing, ndvi

I start to write my own simple code to automatically calculate NDVI from Landsat 5.

Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.analysis import *

land_3 = 'D:\park\LT05_L1TP_131047_19871207_20170418_01_T1_B3.tif'
land_4 = 'D:\park\LT05_L1TP_131047_19871207_20170418_01_T1_B4.tif'

rasterb3 = iface.addRasterLayer(land_3, "B3")
rasterb4 = iface.addRasterLayer(land_4, "B4")

ir = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
r = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()

ir = rasterb4
r = rasterb3

arr = (ir, r, ir, r)

exp = "1.0*(%s-%s)/(1.0*(%s+%s)"%arr

output = 'D:\\park\\output.tif'
e = rasterb3.extent()
w = rasterb3.width()
h = rasterb3.height()
entries = [ir,r]
ndvi = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ndvi = QgsRasterCalculator(exp, output, "GTiff", e, w, h, entries)

ndvi.processCalculation()

lyr = iface.addRasterLayer(output,"NDVI")
```

But this error shown up:

> ```
> Traceback (
> most recent call last):
>   File "D:\QGIS\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
> TypeError: index 0 has type 'QgsRasterLayer' but 'QgsRasterCalculatorEntry' is expected.
> ```

Comment: which line gives the error? It doesn't look like it's `e = rasterb3.extent()`, but line 25 is that in your code.

Comment: my 25th line is  ndvi = QgsRasterCalculator(exp,output,"GTiff",e,w,h,entries)

Comment: there is a missing parentheses in your exp

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignments aren't setting up `QgsRasterCalculatorEntry` properly.
Right now, first you make `ir` (and `r`) empty `QgsRasterCalculatorEntr`ies.
Then you reassign them to be the corresponding layers. That doesn't *initialize* them to have the right values as a `QgsRasterCalculatorEntry`, but *reassigns* them to be the layer instead. Then `exp` uses string operations, but I doubt passing 4 layers to string concatenation coerces that to the layer names (I'm not sure).

The correct way to do this can probably be gleaned from [How to evaluate raster calculator expressions from the console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console/59305)  I think you're on the right track I think with using `QgsRasterCalculatorEntry`, but you will need to set its `.ref` and `.raster` manually, and then use the `.ref` in setting up your `exp`.

[Not tested, not at my QGIS machine today]